# Datatables editable - oDeleteParameters get id of selected row

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I'm trying to pass additional parameters to the ajax call that is done after selecting a row then clicking delete button. Here's the code I have:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDeferLoading": <%= @count %>,
        "sAjaxSource": "redraw",
        "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline
      }).makeEditable({
        sDeleteURL: "delete.rb",
        oDeleteParameters: 
          {
            foo: WHAT IS ID
          }
      });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send a parameter foo=ID but I'm not sure how to grab the selected ID of the row.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the following function mentioned in the link below to get the id's of the rows that have been selected and sending them via ajax to the serverside where they get deleted.
hope this solves what you were looking for...

http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html